# DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED error

Tags: wcf, security, authentication

I'm getting this error when accesssing a WCF service that accesses a .mdb file on disk. It's apparently not a permissions error. Do any of you have familiarity with this error and what might be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer would still be interesting, but the problem "went away". I guess I'll repost when it comes back again :)